How to importing data adapter library of Chart.js in Deno?
I'm using Deno Fresh, and I need to have charts. To render it client-side, on islands/chart.tsx I have:
import { Chart } from "$fresh_charts/island.tsx";
export default Chart;

and on routes/chart.tsx I have this code. This renders the chart fine.
To have time chart, I need to import the date adapter library in routes/chart.tsx. In Node, this is simply:
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';

Since I'm using Deno, directly doing that doesn't work.
Try 1: add npm: specifiers
In routes/chart.tsx I add:
import 'npm:chartjs-adapter-moment';

It doesn't render the chart.
Try 2: copy the source of the adapter
The code seems to be simple and can be easily modified to run in Deno, so I copy it to islands/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.js, add npm: specifiers to its imported modules:
import { _adapters } from "npm:chart.js";
import { ... } from "npm:date-fns";

In routes/chart.tsx I import it as:
import "../islands/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.js";

Still doesn't render the chart.
Try 3: use date-fns Deno package
In islands/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.js I import the modules with:
import { _adapters } from "npm:chart.js";
import { ... } from "https://deno.land/x/date_fns@v2.22.1/index.js";

Then the error is: Module not found "https://deno.land/x/date_fns@v2.22.1/getDay.js" at https://deno.land/x/date_fns@v2.22.1/nextDay/index.ts:2:20
Try 3.1: clone date-fns/deno and fix the paths
No more error, but there is no chart rendered.
Try 4: import $fresh_charts/island.tsx
The imports of islands/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.js are now:
import { _adapters } from "$fresh_charts/island.tsx";
import { ... } from "../utils/deno/index.js";

It says that The requested module '$fresh_charts/island.tsx' does not provide an export named '_adapters'.
Any idea on how to make this works?

Sorry, not a Deno Fresh user. What if if you add import 'npm:chartjs-adapter-moment'; after the line import { Chart } from "$fresh_charts/island.tsx"; in islands/chart.tsx?

If it is still not working, I think that you should use pure Chart.js instead of the Chart.JS from Deno Fresh. Sometimes, it may have some restrictions/limitations when the third-party libraries construct their own component based on the original library.

It doesn't work. As I've already built my project on Deno, I would like to keep using it. The Deno runtime and Fresh framework provide great DX. In the meantime someone has manage to use Apache EChart instead. Discussion here
